# How can I play videos with Jwplayer in Google Drive?

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api, jwplayer

I tried very hard to solve the problem I mentioned in the title . And i played videos with jwplayer. But, only in one resolution. I want that all videos have multiple resolution. For example, i uploaded 1080p video and added jwplayer, jwplayer will convert 360p,720p and 1080p automatically like youtube player and google drive player.

Sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 1):

JW Player is not a server-side application, so it can't do any conversion of the videos. If you upload only a 1080p video, that's the only video that JW Player can display.

It's possible to upload multiple versions of a video, and have JW Player offer different resolutions to the visitor. This is done by specifying multiple sources within a playlist, and providing a different label for each (like 360p, 720p, etc.). But this requires multiple video files.

See http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference

Comment: thanks for reply. Can i change gdrive video player skin?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're using JW Player, you're not using Google Drive at all, so the skin is irrelevant. JW Player supports self-hosted videos, or videos on YouTube. Those are the only choices.

Comment: We don't support Google Drive.